# Select a Single Record from each group in a join based on Max(Char_Length) of Name Field

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

Given a query where I am finding "Name" fields in one table based on matches to another, how can I just keep the match in the first table that has the longest length? I know `Max(Char_Length)` might be a way to find the longest one but not sure how to return it:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2b8b7fa/3

```
Select ID,T1.Name from ShortNames T1
Inner Join LongNames T2
On T2.Name Like Concat('% ', T1.Name)
or T2.Name like Concat(T1.Name,' %')
```

Comment: I tried the following http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2b8b7fa/3 and it seems to work well so far: `Select ID,T1.Name from ShortNames T1
Inner Join LongNames T2
On T2.Name Like Concat('% ', T1.Name)
or T2.Name like Concat(T1.Name,' %')
Group by T2.ID
Order by Max(Char_Length(T1.Name))`

Answer (score 1):

If you need the all the column You could check for the max  length in where on subselect

```
  Select ID,T1.Name 
  from ShortNames T1
  Inner Join LongNames T2
  On T2.Name Like Concat('% ', T1.Name)
  or T2.Name like Concat(T1.Name,' %')

  where length(T1.Name from) = (
    Select max(length(T1.Name from)) 
    FROM ShortNames T1
    Inner Join LongNames T2
    On T2.Name Like Concat('% ', T1.Name)
    or T2.Name like Concat(T1.Name,' %')
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned yourself, you can use Max function:

```
Select Max(T1.Name) from ShortNames T1
Inner Join LongNames T2
On T2.Name Like Concat('% ', T1.Name)
or T2.Name like Concat(T1.Name,' %')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a variation of the [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) problem, which is asked frequently on Stack Overflow.

Here's one way to solve it:

```
SELECT ID, T1.Name FROM ShortNames T1
INNER JOIN LongNames T2
  ON T2.Name LIKE CONCAT('% ', T1.Name)
  OR T2.Name LIKE CONCAT(T1.Name,' %')
LEFT OUTER JOIN LongNames T3
  ON (T3.Name LIKE CONCAT('% ', T1.Name)
  OR T3.Name LIKE CONCAT(T1.Name,' %'))
  AND CHAR_LENGTH(T3.NAME) > CHAR_LENGTH(T2.NAME)
WHERE T3.NAME IS NULL;
```

Explanation: Use an outer join for another row T3 that has a longer name than T2. If none is found, then T2 must be the one with the longest name.

This will unfortunately return multiple results if there are ties.

In MySQL 8.0, they support window functions and CTEs, so this problem can be solved another way (I haven't tested this):

```
WITH ranked_names AS (
  SELECT T1.ID, T1.Name, ROW_NUMBER() 
    OVER (PARTITION BY T1.Name ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(T2.Name) DESC) AS rownum
  FROM ShortNames T1
  INNER JOIN LongNames T2
    ON T2.Name LIKE CONCAT('% ', T1.Name)
    OR T2.Name LIKE CONCAT(T1.Name,' %')
)
SELECT * FROM ranked_names WHERE rownum = 1;
```

This will not return multiple results even if there's a tie.

A third solution would be to keep a column in the ShortNames table that references the preferred row in LongNames.

```
ALTER TABLE ShortNames ADD COLUMN LongestNameId INT;
```

After you populate that column, then you can do simpler joins:

```
SELECT ID, T1.Name, T2.Name FROM ShortNames T1
INNER JOIN LongNames AS T2
  ON T1.LongestNameID = T2.ID
```

That will run with much better performance than your query that does `LIKE` pattern-matching.

Answer (score 0):

I hate answering my own question :| but this seems to work as desired/expected:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2b8b7fa/13

`Select T2.ID,T1.Name from ShortNames T1
Inner Join LongNames T2
On T2.Name Like Concat('% ', T1.Name)
or T2.Name like Concat(T1.Name,' %')
Group by T2.ID 
Order by Max(Char_Length(T1.Name))`